# Updating modules + Updater + Version control + Beanstalk

Tags: git, updating, devdemon-updater

When updating modules locally we typically use DevDemon Updater to shorten the install process. Many modules run SQL queries when updating which is not version controlled.

My question is rather than ignoring the third_party folder in Git and installing the modules twice, what would be the cleanest & quickest way to do module updates and SQL queries with version control? Is there an action to trigger module SQL updates automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use Navicat to sync changes from local into test and then into production after doing an update.

Recently though I've seen http://dbv.vizuina.com/ and when I get the time want to see how we can incorporate that into our current process.

Comment: Do you use 'Data Synchronization' via the Tools menu in Navicat? Is there a certain process to make sure all goes smoothly?

Comment: We have started using this method and its going well. Learning heaps about how ExpressionEngine and Addons store data as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Heres my thought process:**

As you're using Beanstalk (so do we), you could use post hooks to trigger the SQL to run (we don't do that!). It would require a terminal script I guess.

You'd have to isolate the SQL that each module needs to run in the update method of the upd.xxx.php file. Seems like it would be easier to do this manually with each module upgrade.

Then again, if the third_party is under VC, all the new files will be on the live site post deployment. Doesn't EE check the update class by just visiting the 'Modules' screen?